# Scrolling multiple elements/DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to scroll multiple divs at the same time.

I've got something that works, but it's not performant on slow machines (mobiles especially)

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scroller">
            <div>some really long content that just keeps going on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scroller">
            <div>some really long content that just keeps going on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scroller">
            <div>some really long content that just keeps going on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scroller">
            <div>some really long content that just keeps going on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scroller">
            <div>some really long content that just keeps going on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
/* CSS */
    .container { width:300px; }
    .scroller { width:100%; height:40px; padding:0 0 16px; line-height:40px; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:nowrap; }
</style>

<script>
// jQuery
$(".scroller").scroll(function(){
    $(".scroller").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
</script>
```

[Here's a pen/demo](http://codepen.io/russatkins/pen/RNNjBx)

I can see that whevever I scroll an element, that it scrolls the other elements of the same class, but because I've set a scroll 'listener' on that class, the function fires again for each of the other elements because they have been scrolled using the scrollLeft method.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can improve this?

Comment: So, just to clarify: the behaviour of the scrolls all scrolling at the same time is intended and it's just about performance?

Comment: That's right @Markai.

Comment: And should they be updated live, i.e. when the scrollbar is moved, or is it enough, to move them at the end of scrolling?

Comment: Live is ideal, the idea of the interface it to compare in real-time 2 rows of data/text

Answer (score 2):

You could use following snippet: {needs some tests, not sure it handles all cases}

```
$(".scroller").css('outline', 0).attr('tabindex' , -1).scroll(function(e){
    if (!$(this).is(':hover') && !$(this).is(':focus'))  return;
    $(".scroller").not(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: This is definately a lot faster, thanks, although on mobile (android - chrome) it seems like I need to "touchstart" and wait for a few ms until either :focus or :hover is applied.

This can be demonstrated by adding .scroller:hover, .scroller:focus { background-color:#333; } to the css

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the scroll handler from all the elements before calling `scrollLeft()` then re-enable the scroll handlers after.
This will prevent the handler from being called repeatedly.

```
var scrollHandler = function(){
  var $scrollers = $(".scroller");
  $scrollers.off("scroll", scrollHandler);
  $scrollers.scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
  setTimeout(function(){$scrollers.on("scroll", scrollHandler);}, 0);
}

$(".scroller").on("scroll", scrollHandler);
```

Comment: As i see it, you should delay the rebinding: `setTimeout(function(){$scrollers.on("scroll", scrollHandler);}, 0);`

Comment: I guess this is the cleanest way!

Comment: Seems like this is of comparable performance on my phone unfortunately. Nice idea though!

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply only scroll the elements who's scroll position is different?

```
$(".scroller").on('scroll', function(event){
  var a = $(this).scrollLeft();
  $(".scroller").each(function(){
    var b = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if(a !== b){
      $(this).scrollLeft(a);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still fire scroll events for other DIVs. Although I'm not sure what is the exact issue with OP question

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest problem is, that you fire the scroll event on the element you attached the event listener to inside the event listener. If you exclude it from the elements to scroll, you should get a big performance boost on low hardware:

```
$(".scroller").scroll(function(e){
    $(".scroller").not(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: I tried this initially, the problem is, that "$(this).scrollLeft()" re-runs the entire mehod on the other ".scroller", which in turn call themselves...

this can be shown by adding this into the scroll method:
`var $index = $(this).index(".scroller"); // this is the index to ignore.
console.log($index);`